# Shape properties aren't passed correctly between classes when drawing a shape - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, class, object, colors

I'm fairly new to java (been coding for about 8 months) and I'm having a few issues when drawing shapes on JPanel. I can already draw shapes by clicking and dragging my mouse. The issues I have are:

- When I try to pass a color to a class where the shape is being drawn, the color won't update and stays as default color (black).
- When I try to change the pointSize of my shapes (using setStroke method), the first shape I draw correctly updates the pointSize, but the next shape I draw has the default pointSize. (it appears as if the pointSize resets every time I draw a new shape)

Long story short; I think there is something wrong with the way I instantiate new objects and how I pass values to other classes. I have been looking for answers from other people's questions, but I just can't figure out whats wrong.

Here is my code:

my inputHandler class:

```
        package colors;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.util.Random;

    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
    import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;


    public class InputHandler implements ActionListener, MouseInputListener, ChangeListener
    {
        private DrawPanel dp;
        public int pos = 0;
        public String mode = "";
        public String shapeColor = "";
        private double startx;
        private double starty;  

        ButtonPanel bp;
        myRectangle rectangle = new myRectangle();
        myLine line = new myLine();
        myEllipse ellipse = new myEllipse();

        JLabel label;



        public InputHandler(DrawPanel dpanel, ButtonPanel bpanel) 
        {
            this.dp = dpanel;
            this.bp = bpanel;
            dp.addMouseListener(this);
            dp.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }   


        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
        {   

            switch (buttonPressed(e)) //handles the pressed button
            {

                case "Paint":
                    mode = "paint";
                    myRectangle.paint = true;
                    myEllipse.paint = true;
                    break;      

                case "Add Line":
                    mode = "place line";            
                    break;

                case "Add Ellipse":
                    mode = "place ellipse";         
                    break;

                case "Add Rectangle":
                    mode = "place rectangle";           
                    break;  

                case "Delete":              
                    for(int i = dp.shapesList.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
                    {
                        dp.shapesList.remove(i);                    
                    }
                    System.out.println("Canvas cleared.");
                    dp.repaint();
                    break;

                case "Image":
                    mode  = "image";            
                    dp.repaint();
                    break;

                case "Text":
                    mode  = "text";         
                    dp.repaint();
                    break;



                    //colors
                case "red":
                    shapeColor = "red";
                    rectangle.setColor(Color.red);  
                    ellipse.setColor(Color.red);                
                    line.setColor(Color.red);
                    System.out.println("red");
                    break;

                case "blue":
                    shapeColor = "blue";            
                    rectangle.color = Color.blue;
                    ellipse.color = Color.blue;         
                    line.color = Color.blue;
                    System.out.println("blue");
                    break;

                case "green":
                    shapeColor = "green";
                    rectangle.color = Color.green;          
                    ellipse.color = Color.green;                
                    line.color = Color.green;
                    System.out.println("green");
                    break;

                case "yellow":
                    shapeColor = "yellow";          
                    rectangle.color = Color.yellow;
                    ellipse.color = Color.yellow;           
                    line.color = Color.yellow;
                    System.out.println("yellow");
                    break;

                case "black":
                    shapeColor = "black";
                    rectangle.color = Color.black;          
                    ellipse.color = Color.black;                
                    line.color = Color.black;
                    System.out.println("black");
                    break;

                case "purple":
                    shapeColor = "purple";          
                    rectangle.color = Color.magenta;
                    ellipse.color = Color.magenta;          
                    line.color = Color.magenta;         
                    System.out.println("magenta");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }



        public String buttonPressed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            String buttonPressed = e.getActionCommand();        
            return buttonPressed;
        }




        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) 
        {       


            if(mode.equals("paint"))
            {   
                double x = me.getX();
                double y = me.getY();


                for(int i = 0; i<dp.shapesList.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(dp.shapesList.get(i).contains(x, y))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            if(mode.equals("text"))
            {
                System.out.println("test");
                double x = me.getX();
                double y = me.getY();

            }
        }







        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) 
        {


        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) 
        {
            double x = me.getX();
            double y = me.getY();
            startx = me.getX();
            starty = me.getY();

            if(mode.equals("place line"))
            {   
                 line = new myLine(startx,starty,x,y);
                dp.shapesList.add(line);
                dp.repaint();
            }

            if(mode.equals("place rectangle"))
            {       
                 rectangle = new myRectangle(startx,starty,x,y);
                dp.shapesList.add(rectangle);
                dp.repaint();
            }

            if(mode.equals("place ellipse"))
            {   
                 ellipse = new myEllipse(startx,starty,x,y);
                dp.shapesList.add(ellipse);
                dp.repaint();
            }



        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) 
        {
            startx = 0;
            starty = 0;

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) 
        {
            double x = me.getX();
            double y = me.getY();


                if(mode.equals("place line"))
                {   
                     line = new myLine(startx,starty,x,y);
                    dp.shapesList.remove(dp.shapesList.size()-1);
                    dp.shapesList.add(line);
                    dp.repaint();               
                }

                if(mode.equals("place rectangle"))
                {   
                     rectangle = new myRectangle(startx,starty,x,y);
                    dp.shapesList.remove(dp.shapesList.size()-1);
                    dp.shapesList.add(rectangle);
                    dp.repaint();               

                }

                if(mode.equals("place ellipse"))
                {   
                     ellipse = new myEllipse(startx,starty,x,y);
                    dp.shapesList.remove(dp.shapesList.size()-1);
                    dp.shapesList.add(ellipse);
                    dp.repaint();

                }


        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) 
        {

        }


        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) 
        {

            if(ce.getSource() == bp.pointSize)
            {
                rectangle.setStroke(bp.pointSize.getValue());
                ellipse.setStroke(bp.pointSize.getValue());
                line.setStroke(bp.pointSize.getValue());
            }
        }


    }
```

the myRectangle class (class where the rectangle is being drawn):
`           package colors;

```
        import java.awt.BasicStroke;
        import java.awt.Color;
        import java.awt.Graphics2D;
        import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

        public class myRectangle implements Drawable {

            private double x1, y1, x2, y2;
            DrawPanel dp;
            public Color color;
            public static boolean paint;
            public  int pointSize;

            public myRectangle() {

            }

            public myRectangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
                this.x1 = x1;
                this.y1 = y1;
                this.x2 = x2;
                this.y2 = y2;       
            }

            @Override
            public void draw(Graphics2D g) {         
                 double x = getStartX();
                 double y = getStartY();
                 double width = getWidth();
                 double height = getHeight();
                 Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);           
                 g.setColor(color);      
                 g.draw(r);          
                 g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(pointSize));
                 if(paint)
                 {
                     g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);            
                 }

                 System.out.println("rectangle called");
            }





            public boolean contains(double x, double y) {
                return x >= getStartX() && x <= getEndX() && y >= getStartY() && y <= getEndY();
            }

            public double getWidth() {
                return Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            }

            public double getHeight() {
                return Math.abs(y1 - y2);
            }

            public double getStartX() {
                return Math.min(x1, x2);
            }

            public double getStartY() {
                return Math.min(y1, y2);
            }

            public double getEndX() {
                return Math.max(x1, x2);
            }

            public double getEndY() {
                return Math.max(y1, y2);
            }

            public String getShape()
            {
                return "Rectangle";
            }

            public void setStroke(int stroke)
            {
                pointSize = stroke;
            }


            public void setColor(Color color)
            {
                this.color = color;
            }
        }`
```

my DrawPanel class (the class that draws shapes onto the JPanel):`          package colors;

```
        import java.awt.Graphics;
        import java.awt.Graphics2D;
        import java.util.ArrayList;

        import javax.swing.JPanel;

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        public class DrawPanel extends JPanel 
        {
            public ArrayList<Drawable> shapesList = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
            public static int pointSize;



            public DrawPanel()
            {
                super();
            }



            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);            

                // Cast the graphics object to type Graphics2D
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;    
                // Loop through the shapesList and draw every shape
                for(Drawable s : shapesList)
                {   
                    s.draw(g2d);        
                }

            }







        }`
```

And finally here is an image to get a basic understanding of what my program looks like:[image of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZGT4.jpg)

I know this is a lot of code, but I have been struggeling with these problems for a while now and I just can't figure out whats wrong so I finally decided to make a post.

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Mick

Comment: `been coding for about 8 months` - then you should know that class names should start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions.

Comment: Call `repaint` on the instance of `DrawPanel` to trigger a new paint cycle

Answer (score 1):

> Long story short; I think there is something wrong with the way I instantiate new objects and how I pass values to other classes

Yes, you are not setting all the parameters for the shape objects when you create them.

```
rectangle.setColor(Color.red);  
ellipse.setColor(Color.red);                
line.setColor(Color.red);
```

Above you set the color of the existing object when you click the color button.

```
rectangle = new myRectangle(startx,starty,x,y);
dp.shapesList.add(rectangle);
```

But then you create a new object and add the object to the List, but you never set the color.

You need to set all the parameters when you create the object.

The "RED" button, should just set a variable in the class for the next color to be used when a shape object is created.

Check out [Custom Painting](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working examples that sets the color when you draw a Rectangle.

Also, instead of having a "Paint" button, you would typically invoke `repaint()` after adding the shape to the shapeList. There is no need for the "paint" variable. You just paint the shape whenever the draw() method is invoked.

Comment: so you're saying i should make a variable in the myRectangle class, and then change that variable by clicking the RED button? like: rectangle.color = Color.red;  But thats pretty much what setColor does right? it changes the variable "color" in the myRectangle class

Comment: Use proper class names!!! `myRectangle` is NOT a proper class name!!! Read the comments. No, that is NOT what I'm saying. It is just a variable in the class where you define the RED, BLUE and GREEN buttons. A single variable gets set when you click either of the buttons. Then you just use that variable when you create the `MyRectangle` class.

Comment: Basically you just use the `shapeColor` variable, except it needs to be of type Color instead of String.